# Spring MVC controller's constructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to put some initialization methods in controller's default constructor, but the problem that it never called. When I put an @Autowired annotation, the error is throuwn - Autowired annotation requires at least on argument.

What the best practice for putting some initialization code in one place except of putting it in each controller's method?
Thank you

```
@InitBinder 
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) { 
   try { 
      initialize(); 
      Logger l = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()); 
      l.warning("Init!!!"); 
   } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
} 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="de.butler.crm.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="l" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
        <property name="interceptors">
           <list>
            <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
           </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="de.butler.crm.resource.Resources" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="de" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="50000000"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your XML. Can you post your controller class also?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

a) Controllers are just plain Spring Beans, so that all aspects of [the Spring Bean lifecycle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-nature) apply.

I.e. you can [autowire](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-autowire) properties or constructor parameters (with [annotation support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)), you can initialize beans using [the InitializingBean interface](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean) or [a `@PostConstruct` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations) etc.

If none of this works, then there's something wrong with your setup and you'll have to post your web context xml and / or a stack trace.

b) If you need a per-request setup, then use the [`@InitBinder` mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder)

Comment: And that @ItitBinder method will be executed each request?

Comment: By the way, it doesn't help, the controller does not execute that metnod in request

Comment: @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  try {
   initialize();
   
   Logger l = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());
   l.warning("Init!!!");
   
  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
   try {
    eventsLogService.add(new LogEvent(e, currentUser, new Date()));
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
    }

Comment: This construction does not work. Should I add something into configuration file?

Comment: @nKognito a) define "does not work". What happens. b) don't put code blocks in comments, add them to your question

Comment: Happens nothing. The iniBind do not executed.

Comment: @nKognito ok, please add your context.xml to the question

Comment: @nKognito Do you have an controller annotated with '@Controller' in the package defined by base-package="de.butler.crm.controller" ? If you , try replacing '@InitBinder' with '@PostConstruct' as suggested by '@Sean Patrick Floyd' and see if it works .

Answer (score 0):

By default life cycle of bean in spring is managed by Spring container .If you want to initialized your bean with some of your code you can do it with @postconstruct method.

You have to create listener for your bean and whenever your bean is initialized this two method will invoke @postconstruct and @predestroy so you have to use this method for doing things