# How to add a constructor in Controller via Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to initialize three properties (`companyTypes`, `carrierLists`, and `cabinLevels`) as global variables:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/backend/basic")
public class TicketRuleController {
    @Autowired
    private CarrierService carrierService;
    @Autowired
    private CabinLevelService cabinLevelService;
    @Autowired
    private CompanyTypeService companyTypeService;
    private List<DTOCompanyType> companyTypes = companyTypeService.loadAllCompanyTypes();
    private List<DTOCarrier> carrierLists = carrierService.loadAllCarriers();
    private List<DTOCabinLevel> cabinLevels = cabinLevelService.loadAllCabinLevel(); 
    ...
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC controller's constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906685/spring-mvc-controllers-constructor)

Comment: what do you mean by `global`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are few ways to perform your initialization after dependency injection is completed: you can use [@PostConstruct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation on some method. For e.g.:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
   //do your stuff
}
```

Or you can use Spring's [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface. Create a class which implements this interface. For e.g.:

```
@Component
public class MySpringBean implements InitializingBean {


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet()
            throws Exception {
       //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, may I ask a question! i find that the data via @PostConstruct only destory when server stop.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a constructor for initialization.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/backend/basic")
public class TicketRuleController {

    private final CarrierService carrierService;
    private final CabinLevelService cabinLevelService;
    private final CompanyTypeService companyTypeService;

    private final List<DTOCompanyType> companyTypes;
    private final List<DTOCarrier> carrierLists;
    private final List<DTOCabinLevel> cabinLevels; 

    @Autowired
    public TicketRuleController(
            final CarrierService carrierService,
            final CabinLevelService cabinLevelService,
            final CompanyTypeService companyTypeService
        ) {
        super();
        this.carrierService = carrierService;
        this.cabinLevelService = cabinLevelService;
        this.companyTypeService = companyTypeService;
        companyTypes = companyTypeService.loadAllCompanyTypes();
        carrierLists = carrierService.loadAllCarriers();
        cabinLevels = cabinLevelService.loadAllCabinLevel();
    }

    // …
}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Because if you want to use injected properties at initialization time it won't work, because beans won't yet be injected.

Comment: You are right. If you want to call injected properties, it won't work in a constructor.